# How can I determine in PHP if I have write permissions to a folder

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that requires manipulating files in the plugin directory, and I can't figure out how to diagrammatically determine whether PHP has write permissions to a folder. How would I go about achieving this in a relatively simple manner?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$b = is_writable( "/file/or/folder/to/test" ); //boolean value
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Works on files as well as on folders: "Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is writable. The filename argument may be a directory name allowing you to check if a directory is writable."

Comment: Most of the cases, if you want to know if have write permission to the current folder, you can test `is_writable(__FILE__)` which will save you from finding the current path

Answer (score 4):

[fileperms](http://www.php.net/fileperms) gets permissions for the given file.

Answer (score 4):

Try this function: [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-writable.php)